# Accessing a specific element using xpath

Tags: javascript, xpath, titanium, yql

I want to access a specific element using xpath.This is my the result of yql query.Have a look at this link
        http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20content%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A//www.riqapp.be/qld-quaddie.html%22%20and%20xpath%3D%22//h6[1]%22

```
    <h6>First qld Quaddie</h6>
    <h6>second qld quaddie</h6>
```

and i am using this yql query

```
    select content from html where url="http://www.riqapp.be/qld-quaddie.html" and xpath="//h6"
```

Now i want access the only first element using xpath which says First qld Quaddie.Plz help me in this regard

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
(//h6)[1]
```

**This is one of the most FAQ in XPath** -- the XPath `[]` operator has a higher precedence than the `//` XPath pseudo-operator.

Comment: Thanks for such a nice reply

Answer (score 1):

The XPath `//h6[1]` should do the trick. (Tested via http://www.xpathtester.com/.)

Comment: Hi i have tried your solution but this is the result returned in yql console.You could have a search yourself  <results>
        <h6>First qld Quaddie</h6>
        <h6>second qld quaddie</h6>
    </results>

Comment: I don't know YQL well, but am still rather surprised that 'select content from html where url="http://www.riqapp.be/qld-quaddie.html" and xpath="//h6[1]"' doesn't yield the expected result. Even the example at http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-select-xpath.html#html_table-using_xpath makes use of square brackets to select a specific <div> in an (X)HTML page.

Sorry I don't have any other ideas at present aside from the usual "double check and try again" type of advice. :)